# How to find parent element and remove child element text of that parent in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

Here is the markups i have used

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <thead>
            <tr class="tr-head">
                <th>Amount Owed</th>
                <th>Amount Paid</th>
                <th>Check / Cash / Online</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="row0">
                <td>$10 <input type="text" name="amount_owed" id="amount_owed" value="10" style="display: none; width: 40px;" /></td>
                <td>$20 <input type="text" name="amount_paid" id="amount_paid" value="20" style="display: none; width: 40px;" /></td>
                <td>$30 <input type="text" name="check_cash_online" id="check_cash_online" value="30" style="display: none; width: 40px;" /></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="edit-row" title="row0">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row1">
                <td>$10 <input type="text" name="amount_owed" id="amount_owed" value="10" style="display: none; width: 40px;" /></td>
                <td>$20 <input type="text" name="amount_paid" id="amount_paid" value="20" style="display: none; width: 40px;" /></td>
                <td>$30 <input type="text" name="check_cash_online" id="check_cash_online" value="30" style="display: none; width: 40px;" /></td>
                <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="edit-row" title="row1">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I want to remove first three child cell `td` text (i.e. $10, $20....) except `input` element when i click on Edit of particular row. Input type should be show After hiding text of cell. Please help me how can i make it using jquery script. thanks

I have tried some script to do this i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.edit-row').click(function(){
                    var title = $(this).attr('title');
                    $('.'+title+' td').text('');
                });
        });
```

But above script making cell empty.

Comment: Great question, by the way! There are a lot of people out there who are very comfortable with jQuery, but not so comfortable with vanilla JavaScript and direct DOM manipulation. This question may help a lot of people bridge that gap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will work for you:

```
​$('.edit-row​​').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').not(':last')
        .contents().filter(
            function() {
                return this.nodeType == 3;
            }).remove();
});​
```

Tested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YVa9k/1/).

Zachary Kniebel hit it with the **.contents()** method

Sorry, I forgot the part where the input elements are shown:

```
$('.edit-row').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').not(':last').contents()
        .filter(
            function() {
                return this.nodeType != 3;
            })
        .show().parent().contents()
        .filter(
            function() {
                return this.nodeType == 3;
            }).remove();
});​
```

Tested and working.

Comment: yeah, this is definitely the easiest version for this solution - I added the for-loop into mine, just in case he or another reader wanted to customize it a bit more. The only thing that I would suggest is removing the `:last` selector and using a loop to find the first three - the number may change in the future

Comment: If the number of cells change in the future, it is always best to use **:last** because that's more likely be the cell containing the **edit** link, don't you think?

Comment: In this situation, you are definitely right. In other situations, however, I think it might be better to select the cells that you are looking for based on amount or location, simply because the edit button might not stay where it is. My coding style is to write everything so that I can adapt it with minimal modification in future scenarios.

Comment: Good call on the displaying inputs, by the way. I forgot about that one too.

Comment: Another good approach would be to add a class to the cells with the inputs and act upon them instead of the **:last** selector and the loop you suggested :)

Answer (score 1):

Look up jQuery's `.contents()` method. It will return all text, element, and content nodes of the calling element/collection. What you will want to do is create a filter method, like so:

```
var filterNodes = function() {
    return this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 3;
}
```

Which will return all element and text nodes. From there, select the element nodes that you want to remove the text from and remove the text nodes.

NOTE: The `.contents()` method returns CHILDREN not DESCENDANTS

**EDIT:**

I re-read your question, and I think this would better suit you:

1. Loop through the first three `td`'s using a standard jQuery selector
2. Run the following filter method, to only get the text nodes:

   `var filterNodes = function () {
       return this.nodeType == 3;
   }`
3. Call the filter method like so:

   `var firstThreeTDs = ....`

   `var nodeSet = firstThreeTDS.contents().filter(filterNodes).toArray();`

   `for (var i = 0; i < nodeSet.length; i++) {`

   ```
       nodeSet[i].parentNode.removeChild(nodeSet[i]);`
   ```

   `}`
4. Use the `.show()` method, the `.css()` method, or an effect method (fade, slide, etc.) to show the input box

**EDIT 2:**

There is an alternative solution, but it's not the best, it's untested, and it would take a good amount of debugging time (especially because you might lose some properties/attributes, based on your implementation): you could use jQuery's `clone()` method, to duplicate the input elements in each `td`, and then use the `.html()` method to set the `td`'s inner HTML to that duplicated input element. It's not a good solution, it's more overhead, and it's a bit more novice, but it would work if you are uncomfortable with manipulating the DOM, manually.

Let me know if you need any more help/clarification. Good Luck! :)

Comment: Sorry about the formatting - formatting code in lists is kind of difficult on SO

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.row0 #amount_owed,.row0 #amount_paid,row0 #check_cash_online').remove();
```

Comment: This will do the opposite of what nilesh1006 wants.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.edit-row').click(function(){
       $(this).parents("tr").find('td').not(":last").hide().html("");
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bLygN/2/

Comment: that first one will hide the entire cell, and the second one will clear out all of the html - that isn't what the questioner wanted - he wanted just the text gone, but the input box to stay

Comment: almost, but each `td` is also supposed to have a textbox in it, which shouldn't be removed with the text (dollar amount)

Comment: when each of the cells are cleared, you want there to still be an input element - you're on the right track, but when you click 'edit' you want to still see the input boxes